# Video Production SE Needs One More Moderator - Anyone Interested?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

Now that the dust has settled, what was formerly for audio & video is now purely about video. Video Production SE survived in *great* shape, in fact better than it was. We had [two moderators step up](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/who-should-the-new-moderators-be) in the last call, but we like for each site to have a team of three. Not only does this provide a more balanced team (with a tie-breaker if one is needed), it also helps to ensure that the site has adequate moderator coverage as people phase in and out of activity.

Check out the original post I linked above, the gist is pretty much this:

> Moderators should be:
>
> - Consistently patient and fair in their interactions with new users
> - Able to give an hour or two of their time each week to moderate
> - Interested in having the responsibility of being a moderator
> - Knowledgeable in the major tags to the point that they can judge the quality of a post, though high reputation is definitely not a
>     requirement

Would you like to be considered for the position? Do you think someone else would do a great job? Let us know in the answers below, just link to your profile on the main site (or, if making a third-party nomination, link to *their* profile) and let us know why you/they would be a great choice.

I normally just look through the ranks of users to make a single pick, but the split has basically skewed everything - It's hard to see who moved over to SD, or who has just been inactive for a while, etc. The picture is becoming clearer since some time has passed, but hearing from you will really help to expedite things.

Comment: And if you are worried about the level of responsibility, it really isn't that bad.  You need to be able to take it seriously before you take actions, but it really isn't a major (or even significant) time sink at all, particularly on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to volunteer as a Moderator aswell. I love the whole stackexchange ecosystem and have been active on this stackexchange for a year now. I have about 7-8 years of experience with video production especially Animation and VFX. A good 3 years of that professionally in the advertisement industry.
I also know a lot about video and sound formats and worked with a ton of diffrent software in this industry on all 3 major operating systems.

While I was mostly active on StackOverflow the past 2 years, because I learned to program a few years ago, I would love to become more active on VP. I answered a few questions here and I think I can offer a good service as a moderator with my broad knowledge in this area and having years of experiences with managing online communities.

I think the reason why I wasn't regulary active so far on VP is because its still a very small community and didn't offer all that much to me on a professional level.

It needs to grow a bit more to attract a bigger and more diverse user base like StackOverflow.
The potential to become a huge stackexchange site is there and I hope I can dedicate some time to help it become just that.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to moderate the Video Production SE. I only just signed up for Stack Exchange, but I've been browsing it for a while without an account. I have about 8 years of video editing experience, of which nearly a year professionally, and thusly I consider myself quite knowledgeable on the topic.
I certainly won't mind spending my free time to moderate the site at all.

EDIT: forgot a link to my profile, here it is: http://stackexchange.com/users/4336043/kutmelchior

Comment: I certainly love the level of activity you've been showing on the site.  Btw, if you want a quick rep boost and can answer either of the [featured question](http://video.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) bounties that would help you get to review queue with or without mod powers too.  Also, feel free to hop in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12905/video-production) sometime if you're interested in more active dialog.

Comment: Well when I found out this site existed yesterday I couldn't help but be enthusiastic. I've looked at the bounty questions but sadly I have no experience with kdenlive or Final Cut.

Comment: hehe, that's the same reason I put a bounty on them.  I don't either. :(